# how to replace asset folder by server url for video play

Tags: android, video-streaming

I can paly video from asset folder but i want to play it from server now. How can i change in my app?

source code is

```
  class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {
    protected Object doInBackground(String... args) {
        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        String fileName = args[0];
        File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName);
        Log.i("sushi", "Background thread starting");

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            try {
                InputStream in = am.open("pages/rice/test2.3gp");
                FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }
                f.close();
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("sushi", e.getMessage());
            }

            if (VideoActivity.this.pd != null) {
                VideoActivity.this.pd.dismiss();
                VideoActivity.this.pd = null;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The above code plays video nicely from `assets/pages/..` folder. But i want to take video file from server and play in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.server.at/file");
InputStream in = url.openStream();
```

The rest of your code should stay pretty much the same.

More information at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

Comment: Thank you very much MR.TomTasche. It is working properly. Thank you again.